# Using pointers to access friend class member functions

Tags: c++, pointers, friend

Here are two classes

```
  class A{
    A(int val):Val(val){}
    int getVal(){return Val;}
    friend class B;
    private:
    int Val;
  }


 class B{
    B(A* ptr):PTR(ptr){}
    private:
    A* PTR;
  }
```

In the main function I create the objects for both classes

```
 A objA;
 B objB(&objA)
```

As you can see, objB now contains a pointer to the address of objA. The problem I am facing is how do I use a pointer from objB to access to member function in objA.

Comment: You are looking for `PTR->Val`

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Can you post sample code that you would like to have, and how you expect them to work?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to making objects of type A point at an object of type B and vice versa, you could use a setter instead of passing the instance through constructor arguments as such:

```
  class A{
        A(int val):Val(val){}
        int getVal(){return Val;)
        void setB(B* ptr) {BPtr= ptr;}
        friend class B;
        private:
        int Val;
        B* BPtr
  }


 class B{
        B(A* ptr):PTR(ptr){}
        private:
        A* PTR;
  }
```

And now, when you create A and B objects, you can do this:

```
 A objA;
 B objB(&objA);
 A.setB(&objB);
```

EDIT:

Ok, I misunderstood your question at first. If you're just looking to access a member of an object of type A, you would just do `objA->field` or `(*objA).field` .

Comment: could you please repost the code that included the setter pointer as I think that is closer to the solution.

Comment: Here yo go, I just wasn't sure if you actually also wanted a pointer to an object of type B in objects of type A.

Comment: which part? Can you be clearer on what you actually want to do?